# Is it correct to say "compiled an album"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs

Is it correct to say “compiled an album”?

I basically want to convey the idea that I originally had a set of photographs out of which I have selected a few of them and made an album. It would also be great if anyone can suggest some other phrase to convey the same idea.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the phrase  “compiled an album”.  Your question, on the other hand, may get closed as ”not a real question” or “off topic”.  See [faq] and improve question.

Comment: I class it as General Reference.

Comment: If all the photographs are your own (i.e., belong to you, not your picture) and you had already had them with you, then '*compiled*' would be just too much. *Album* itself conveys the required meaning, so you only need to say you *made an album* of select photographs.

Comment: Not exactly GR -- there's substance and relevance in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a pretty common term. From Macmillan:

> **compile**, *tr. v.*: to make something such as a list or book by bringing together information from many different places

Another word in a similar vein that's in popular use is *curate*:

> **curate**, *v*: to pull together, sift through, and select for presentation

However, *curate* tends to be more specific than *compile*; one would curate an album of works by a single photographer, or on a specific subject, for example.

Comment: Agreed. However, these words seem too heavy for the context. Pl see my comment at OP.

Comment: @Kris What context? Also, _album_ is not a verb, and the OP is asking for a verb for the act of selecting photographs from a set and putting them into an album.

Comment: You can also "_put together_ an album".

Comment: @Gnawme "*Made*" is the simple verb in "*made an album*". That should do. The nature and quality of the verb is conveyed by the characteristics of the noun "**album**": *A collection ... as a single item*. You don't 'compile' a collection, or need to do anything else. I had to post the above comment because both *compile* and *curate* have specialized meanings, esp., with regard to art objects such as photographs.

Comment: @Kris But the OP's question asks, "Is it correct to say, 'Compiled an album.'" In an ordinary conversation, most native speakers would have no trouble understanding you, and very few, if any, would think your use of _compile_ specialized.

Answer (score -1):

Photo Compilation Album would fit better.
I assume that you first made a photo compilation, then
you provided an album for your photo compilation.
That's why I would call it a photo compilation album.